# MySQL Stored procedure returning empty results

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`thinktosco_com`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetQuestions`(IN languageId CHAR(36), IN userId CHAR(36), IN _limit INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `QuestionTranslation` 
    WHERE `LanguageId` = languageId
    AND Phase != 'HISTORY'
    AND `QuestionId` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `QuestionId` FROM `Answer` WHERE `UserId` = userId)
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT _limit;
END
```

When running the select statement I get the correct result, but when running the stored procedure like the following, I get no results:

```
CALL thinktoscore_com_db.GetQuestions('9997f94d-1b90-11e3-92c0-0050568243f2', '9d6a59d9-ee09-41d7-896b-7c9930e324dd', 12);
```

The table QuestionTranslation contains 1132 rows, and the Answer table contains 484 rows matching userId = '9d6a59d9-ee09-41d7-896b-7c9930e324dd'. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

/ Søren

Answer (score 0):

in your call to the Stored-Procedure, your parameter #1 "languageId" looks an awful lot like parameter #2 "userId".

```
CALL thinktoscore_com_db.GetQuestions(
    '9997f94d-1b90-11e3-92c0-0050568243f2', 
    '9d6a59d9-ee09-41d7-896b-7c9930e324dd', 
    12);
```

Are you sure that '9997f94d-1b90-11e3-92c0-0050568243f2' is a **languageId** ?

Comment: Yes. I am using UUID for both of them, so they do look alike.

Comment: aha ... ok ... just looked like something too obvious